# Use LINQ to convert List of Dictionary to strongly Typed Class object List

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, .net-6.0

I am working on .NET CORE 6 app and I have `Dictionary` with structured as

```
 Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>> dataDictionary
```

I have pull list of Dictionary based on `List<Dictionary<int, string>> filteredDictionary` as below

```
var filteredDictionary = dataDictionary.Values.ToList();
```

Each list has 17 dictionary that represent properties of class `AIMSchema` where each property is represented by `key (Int) no`. So I know value at dictionary index 0 present TransactionDate, 1 represent MachineCode and so on... The object is I want convert this dictionary list to `List<AIMSchema>`

I can do in loop as below but I want to do using LINQ

```
foreach (var schema in dataDictionary.Values)
 {
    if(schema != null)
       {
          var aimSchema = new AIMSchema
          {
              TransactionDate = schema[0],
              MachineCode = schema[1],
              // ... other properties
          }
        }
```

Comment: Why Linq? An even better option would be through the DLR and dynamic objects.

Comment: I am open to see best option i.e. DLR but need an example how I can achieve it?

Comment: What is your objection to the current approach you have, any why do you think LINQ is a better solution?

Comment: @K.Z Look at the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject?view=net-6.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm going to provide exactly what you asked for as an answer. The LINQ equivalent of your existing code would look like this:

```cs
List<AIMSchema> result = dataDictionary.Values
    .Where(schema => schema != null)
    .Select(schema => new AIMSchema
    {
        TransactionDate = schema[0],
        MachineCode = schema[1],
        // ... other properties
    })
    .ToList();
```

The `.Where` is a filter, equivalent to your `if (schema != null)`, and the `.Select` is a projection which turns the entry into an `AIMSchema` object. As we're still dealing with a query on `dataDictionary.Values` at this stage, the `.ToList()` materializes the result into a `List<AIMSchema>`.